# Bind session data in grid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to load session data in grid but no data is loaded my code is

```
protected void imageAddExtraField_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        List<ContentInfo> lstExtraFields = new List<ContentInfo>();
        if (Session["ExtraField"] != null)
        {
            lstExtraFields = Session["ExtraField"] as List<ContentInfo>;
        }
        else
        {
            ContentInfo obj = new ContentInfo();
            obj.ExtraFieldValue = ckEditorExtraField.Text;
            obj.ExtraField = ddlExtraField.SelectedItem.ToString();
            lstExtraFields.Add(obj);
            gdvExtraField.DataSource = lstExtraFields;
            gdvExtraField.DataBind();
            Session["ExtraField"] = lstExtraFields;
        }
    }
```

i am using **VS2008** any solution thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your intention, but when is something in the `Session["ExtraFiled"]`, `imageAddExtraField_Click` does nothing with it. If you want to add more objects you might need to refactor a bit the code:

```
protected void imageAddExtraField_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {        
        // check if nothing in the session, on success create a new list
        if (Session["ExtraField"] == null)
        {
            Session["ExtraField"] = new List<ContentInfo>();
        }
        // get a reference to the list in session; previous code ensures is something
        List<ContentInfo> lstExtraFields = (List<ContentInfo>)Session["ExtraField"];
        ContentInfo obj = new ContentInfo();
        obj.ExtraFieldValue = ckEditorExtraField.Text;
        obj.ExtraField = ddlExtraField.SelectedItem.ToString();
        lstExtraFields.Add(obj);

        // bind the grid
        gdvExtraField.DataSource = lstExtraFields;
        gdvExtraField.DataBind();

        // how do you bind when !PostBack?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the ExtraField is List object. 2. make sure the gridview is programmed to display the data (automatic column generation or manual column generation).